# itext pdf in tapestry

Tags: tapestry, itextpdf

I am working on `itext pdf` when I am extending a `PdfPageEventHelper`  class it is showing following errror.

```
Base class com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper (super class of 
de.fu_berlin.inf.klausurenportal.pages.question.TableHeader) is not in a controlled package
 and is therefore not valid. You should try moving the class to package 
de.fu_berlin.inf.klausurenportal.base.
```

Comment: Classes that have my name (Lowagie) in their package name are obsolete and should no longer be used. Please upgrade to a more recent iText version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your component is extended from `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper` class that is not within the tapestry controlled packages. All super classes for tapestry5 components and pages should be placed within `root.base` package.

http://tapestry.apache.org/component-classes.html#ComponentClasses-ComponentPackages

But you can implement `PdfPageEvent` interface instead. You can even create something similar to `PdfPageEventHelper` class in `root.base` package and extend it.

But do you really need this class in your component? You can use `PdfPageEvent` implementation as a separate class, e.g. as an inner class of a page or as an utility class.